# Conditional early exit from full test suite in Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have a parameterized pytest test suite. Each parameter is a particular website, and the test suite runs using Selenium automation. After accounting for parameters, I have hundreds of tests in total, and they all run sequentially.

Once a week, Selenium will fail for a variety of reasons. Connection lost, could not instantiate chrome instance, etc. If it fails once in the middle of a test run, it'll crash all upcoming tests. Here's an example fail log:

```
test_example[parameter] failed; it passed 0 out of the required 1 times.
    <class 'selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException'>
    Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
    [<TracebackEntry test.py:122>, <TracebackEntry another.py:92>, <TracebackEntry /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:669>, <TracebackEntry /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:321>, <TracebackEntry /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242>]
```

Ideally, I'd like to exit the suite as soon as a Selenium failure has occurred, because I know that all the upcoming tests will also fail.

Is there a method of this kind:

```py
def pytest_on_test_fail(err): # this will be a pytest hook
    if is_selenium(err):      # user defined function
        pytest_earlyexit()    # this will be a pytest function
```

Or some other mechanism that will let me early exit out of the full test suite based on the detected condition.

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379412/pytest-mark-a-test-as-a-must-pass-and-stop-testing-if-it-fails
or
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66044498/stop-pytest-tests-if-several-tests-have-a-specific-exception

Comment: @Tzane Thanks, these links were helpful for me to create the answer which I have posted below. Happy to encourage if anybody else has better ideas on how to do this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing I got this to work. This uses the [`pytest_exception_interact`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) hook and the [`pytest.exit`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-exit) function.
WebDriverException is the parent class of all Selenium issues (see [source code](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/common/exceptions.html)).

```py
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    error_class = call.excinfo.type
    is_selenium_issue = issubclass(error_class, WebDriverException)
    if is_selenium_issue:
        pytest.exit('Selenium error detected, exiting test suite early', 1)
```